# maximum number of points that can be placed in a square of area 2 units squared such that no two points are closer to each other than 2/3 units?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

What is the maximum number of points that can be placed in a square of area $2$ units squared such that no two points are closer to each other than 2/3 units?

Initally, this seemed to me like a problem for the pigeonhole principle, however I gave up on that idea and just used common sense. I drew the following picture:

[image]

This shows you can fit 9 points which are all 2/3 units away from each other, however, the maximum is apparently 8. I feel I have made a simple mistake, could anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does the square in your picture have the correct area?

Comment: I think so. I have shown that you can fit 9 points in a square with area 16/9 which is less than 2.

Comment: Yes, you did fit 9 points 2/3 units away from each other in a square of area 2.